# Pagination in wpf Grid

Tags: wpf, pagination

Is there any control available for Pagination in WPF as that of Bootstrap in Web???
If not than what is the way to do Pagination in WPF Grid-Control??
Not only Grid ,if there any other option apart from this then please suggest.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no controls in WPF with built in Pagination. The thing that comes close is a DataGrid.

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1092189/WPF-Pagination-for-DataGrid) is a good example of pagination using DataGrid. You can modify as per your requirements.